# How can I read the value of pointer in C# and convert the value to string?

Tags: c#, pointers

How can I define a pointer and read / write the other variable with it?

and how can I show the value of pointer in the textbox?

Comment: @SnareChops Sure C# has pointers.  Almost no C# devs ever use them, or need to use them, but they exist.

Comment: do you know about unsafe in C#? SnareChops

Comment: Show your attempts at this so we can see where the problem is located. If you have no attempt yet, do that first.

Comment: @Servy That's why I said "C# doesn't *really* have pointers". Poor phrasing, my mistake. I know they exist but as you said are very rarely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcbcf4ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (note, this should be compiled with `/unsafe` switch)

```
int number;

unsafe 
{
    // Assign the address of number to a pointer:
    int* p = &number;

    // Commenting the following statement will remove the
    // initialization of number.
    *p = 0xffff;

    // Print the value of *p:
    System.Console.WriteLine("Value at the location pointed to by p: {0:X}", *p);

    // Print the address stored in p:
    System.Console.WriteLine("The address stored in p: {0}", p->ToString());
}

// Print the value of the variable number:
System.Console.WriteLine("Value of the variable number: {0:X}", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a Pointer by calling &[Name of your Variable]
The Type of Pointers is [Type of your Variable]*

```
long number = 3;
long* ptr = &number;
```

You can change the Type of your pointer. This can end very dirty.

```
int* dirtyPtr = ((int*)ptr) + 1; //Takes only the second half of the long(8 Bytes) as int(4 Bytes)
// +1 refers to the length to the type, so you go 4 Bytes ahead
```

You can change the value of the variable behind the pointer with *[Name of Pointer] = Value

```
*dirtyPtr = 50;
```